# Unable to resolve service for type 'Models.Dto.ResponseDTO' while attempting to activate 'Controllers.CartAPIController'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня возникла проблема с корзиной. Я не могу понять как ее решить. Прошу помочь.

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Services.ShoppingCartAPI;
using Services.ShoppingCartAPI.Data;
using Services.ShoppingCartAPI.Extensions;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
IMapper mapper = MappingConfig.RegisterMaps().CreateMapper();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.AddSecurityDefinition(name: "Bearer", securityScheme: new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Description = "Enter the Bearer Authorization string as following: 'Bearer Generated-JWT-Token'",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type= ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id =JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                    }
                }, new string[]{ }
        }
    });
});
builder.AddAppAutherization();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
ApplyMigration();
app.Run();

void ApplyMigration()
{
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var _db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

        if (_db.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count() > 0)
        {
            _db.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

Код из самого контроллера

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Services.ShoppingCartAPI.Data;
using Services.ShoppingCartAPI.Models;
using Services.ShoppingCartAPI.Models.Dto;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

namespace Services.ShoppingCartAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/car")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CartAPIController : ControllerBase
    {
        private ResponseDTO _response;
        private IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;

        public CartAPIController(ResponseDTO response, IMapper mapper, AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            this._response = new ResponseDTO();
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpPost("CartUpsert")]
        public async Task<ResponseDTO> CartUpsert(CartDTO cartDto)
        {
            try
            {
                var cartHeaderFromDb = await _db.CartHeaders.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == cartDto.CartHeader.UserId);
                if (cartHeaderFromDb == null)
                {
                    //create header and details
                    CartHeader cartHeader = _mapper.Map<CartHeader>(cartDto.CartHeader);
                    _db.CartHeaders.Add(cartHeader);
                    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    cartDto.CartDetails.First().CartHeaderId = cartHeader.CartHeaderId;
                    _db.CartDetails.Add(_mapper.Map<CartDetails>(cartDto.CartDetails.First()));
                    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    //if header is not null
                    //check if details has same product
                    var cartDetailsFromDb = await _db.CartDetails.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(
                        u => u.ProductId == cartDto.CartDetails.First().ProductId &&
                        u.CartHeaderId == cartHeaderFromDb.CartHeaderId);
                    if (cartDetailsFromDb == null)
                    {
                        //create cartdetails
                        cartDto.CartDetails.First().CartHeaderId = cartHeaderFromDb.CartHeaderId;
                        _db.CartDetails.Add(_mapper.Map<CartDetails>(cartDto.CartDetails.First()));
                        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //update count in cart details
                        cartDto.CartDetails.First().Count += cartDetailsFromDb.Count;
                        cartDto.CartDetails.First().CartHeaderId += cartDetailsFromDb.CartHeaderId;
                        cartDto.CartDetails.First().CartDetailsId += cartDetailsFromDb.CartDetailsId;
                        _db.CartDetails.Update(_mapper.Map<CartDetails>(cartDto.CartDetails.First()));
                        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                }
                _response.Result = cartDto;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _response.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
                _response.IsSuccess = false;
            }
            return _response;
        }
    }
}
```

Код ResponseDTO

```
public class ResponseDTO
{
    public object? Result { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; } = true;
    public string Message { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Comment: Зачем вообще в конструкторе сделан параметр `ResponseDTO response`? Убрать его.

Comment: Вы у контроллера делаете зависимость `public CartAPIController(ResponseDTO response, ...)`, то есть класс `CartAPIController` строго зависит от `ResponseDTO` и ряда других объектов. Теперь два вопроса: 1. Зачем этот класс в конструкторе, если он не используется, а создается новый (`_response = new ResponseDTO();`)? 2. Если эта зависимость нужна, то где эта зависимость зарегистрированная в контейнере? Где `builder.Services.Add...<ResponseDTO>();`? Решите сначала что вы хотите, а потом будем думать что не так в вашем коде.

Comment: Убрал ResponseDTO response с конструкотора